# AWS lambda unable to send smtp email

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda, smtp

I have a simple AWS lambda request handler running that sends an email using smtp. When I put this code into a local `main()` function, it runs well and sends the email. When running on aws, I keep getting the following `javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 Syntax: HELO <hostname>` error. Is there something that needs to be changed in AWS for the mail to go through? Here is my code:

```
Properties mailProps = new Properties();
mailProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", sesHost);
mailProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
mailProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", user);
mailProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
PasswordAuthentication auth = new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
mailSession = Session.getInstance(mailProps, new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return auth;
    }
});

String toAddress = "example@example.com";

try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("noreply@example.com", "Example"));
    message.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toAddress));
    message.setSubject("test subject");
    message.setContent("content content","text/html; charset=utf-8");

    System.out.println("Sending email to" + toAddress);

    Transport.send(message);
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Failed to send email");
}
```

Comment: Line 2 of the code you posted has STMP; should your var be SMTP? Also, are you using SES? Are you out of the sandbox?

Comment: @hephalump yeah I'm using SES, line 2 is just a random variable I added, in my code I've hard-coded the credentials for testing (normally I'll be getting the values from mongodb). Yes, I'm out of the sandbox

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem ?

Comment: @MouradZouabi No I have not, I believe this might be an issue with some AWS configuration. But this project has been put on hold, so I haven't had the chance to explore it

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to attach a Security Group with your Lambda which has port 25 open in its outbound rules.

In the Lambda configurations -

Select VPC (create one if there is no existing VPC in account)

Select subnets (create more than one in multiple AZs)

Select the Security group (which has port 25 open in Outbound rules or All traffic permission)

This should work.